# Expand the name of a template parameter in C++

Tags: c++, templates

If I have a function such as:

```
template <class T>
T myFunc(){
    return T_run();
}
```

So if I call `myFunc<int>()`, it should internally invoke int_run(). 
If I call `myFunc<MyClass>()`, it should internally invoke MyClass_run().

This requires T_run to be expanded by substituting T with the name of the template argument.

Is this possible in C++?

Thanks,

Yash

Answer (score 1):

You can't perform arbitrary function name substitutions like that in c++. What you can do is provide specialisations on the function template, like so:

```
template <class T>
T myFunc();

template <>
int myFunc<int>() { return 3; }

template <>
MyClass myFunc<MyClass>() { return MyClass(); }

void foo() {
    int a = myFunc<int>();
    MyClass b = myFunc<MyClass>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this using templates but if you really must you can achieve the same thing with a macro:

```
#define myFunc(T) T##_run()

myFunc(int);     // calls int_run()
myFunc(MyClass); // calls MyClass_run()
```

The `##` operator joins tokens, so it allows you to construct function names during preprocessing.